# jquery ui plugin worked in reactJS, but not working when included in parent project

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, reactjs, webpack

This is my task now,

1. I need to use reactJS to develop component library;
2. I need to use the component library inside other applicaitons, such as backbone project.

I now met a strange issue and can not resolve it. Hope to hear your advice;

First, inside reactJS project, I need to use jqueryUI resizable to resize a component, then I put this:

```
require("script!../../../lib/jquery-2.2.3.min.js");
require("script!../../../lib/jquery-ui.min.js");
```

into my jsx file, and then I can use $('.a').resizable() to resize it. And it is already running fine in this project itself.

Now, I included this exported js file into a backbone project, which already has its own jquery, jueryUI included, then when I load this component inside backbone view, I see this error:

```
VM3800:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).resizable is not a function(…)
```

I suspected the jquery and jqueryUI inside reactJS project conflicted with the parent project in backbone as that also has jquery and jqueryUI included?

How to hear your advice on how to resolve this.